# Centering a row of images where each has its own caption

Tags: html, css

I want to center a row consisting of four images and their respective captions below them.
Currently I'm using

```
<div class="clear" style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;">
    <img>...</img>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div style...
</div>
```

Obviously that doesn't get the containers centered, because they're floating. I have read of a solution, that would work wonderfully:

```
style="display: inline-block;"
```

So I went and used that very style and made my code look like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 10px">
    <img>...</img>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now as I mentioned, this worked out wonderfully and in the preview it did exactly what I wanted it to, however, here's where the problem starts.
I'm trying to do this as part of a short news article on a website, the website offers a fairly extensive editor which has a function that let's you write your own HTML code. For some reason that I cannot comprehend, there seems to be some script running over the code when you save the post, that removes the “display: inline-block;” part.

Is there any alternative for it that I can try? I'm deliberately trying to avoid using a table for this, as I'm not sure how well it will scale when it's being viewed on smaller displays like a smart phone.

Comment: How to make a class and apply to the div? With this method, parsers don't removes you the inline-block declaration.

Comment: Have you tried using jquery to add the display that way?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I seem to have phrased that badly ... The editor I'm working in creates the post I write within a DIV-block. I cannot create a new style class in there.

Comment: @ChrisG As mentioned above all the editing and post-creating happens within a single DIV-block, the editor won't allow me to use any scripts in there. They're immediatly filtered out.

Comment: What editor do you use? CKEditor? I don't have any issues with that in years of development with CKEditor. Don't you have any working example of your problem?

Comment: This sounds like you should be changing the script that's deleting your code not trying to hack the CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, that's what I'll have the administrator do once he's back, but I am only a user of that page, who writes short articles from time to time. I have no access to those scripts, I cannot make any changes like that. I can only try to work my way around obstacles like these, but this time I feel like it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Just use css classes ?

```
.container{
text-aling:center;
}
.container > div{
display:inline-block;
}
```

And in the HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
   ....
</div>
```